# apt-get and Software Center tries to remove core packages

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, dpkg, compiling

Recently(before I got Ethernet wired on 12.04.01) I tried to install build-essentials and its dependences through .deb files, and failed ultimately so I gave up. Now, I tried to apt-get it now that I have internet, and this is now returned:

```
luke@luke-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.16) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is to be installed
 libimobiledevice4 : Depends: libgcrypt11 (>= 1.5.1) but 1.5.0-3ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libgnutls26 (>= 2.12.17-0) but 2.12.14-5ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libtasn1-6 (>= 3.4-0) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libusbmuxd2 (>= 1.0.8) but it is not installable
 libnih1 : PreDepends: libc6 (< 2.16) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is to be installed
 libwxgtk2.8-0 : Depends: libesd-alsa0 (>= 0.2.35) but it is not installable or
                          libesd0 (>= 0.2.35) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libjpeg62 but it is not going to be installed
 perl : Depends: perl-base (= 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.4) but 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
        Depends: perl-modules (>= 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.4) but 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
 python-wxgtk2.8 : Depends: python (< 2.6) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
                   Depends: python-central (>= 0.6) but it is not going to be installed
 python-wxversion : Depends: python (< 2.6) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
                    Depends: python-central (>= 0.6) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I tried doing `sudo apt-get -f install` and it now tries to uninstall many core packages essential to the system:

```
luke@luke-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  wireless-regdb iw crda libgeis1 libframe6 libgrail5
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  brasero-cdrkit brasero-common compiz-core compiz-plugins-default
  empathy-common gir1.2-totem-1.0 libapt-pkg4.12 libbrasero-media3-1
  libdecoration0 libept1.4.12 libframe6 libgeis1 libgrail5 libhpmud0
  libperl5.14 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common
  libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-impress
  libreoffice-math libreoffice-writer libtotem0 libunity-core-5.0-5
  libvte-common libvte9 libwxbase2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-0 nautilus-sendto-empathy
  perl-base perl-modules printer-driver-hpijs python-uno python-wxgtk2.8
  python-wxversion synaptic totem totem-common totem-plugins unity-services
  uno-libs3 ure
Suggested packages:
  dvdauthor readom gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly cdrdao libreoffice-base
  libreoffice-style-hicontrast libreoffice-style-crystal
  libreoffice-style-oxygen libreoffice-gcj libreoffice-filter-binfilter
  default-jre gcj-jre java-gcj-compat openjdk-6-jre openjdk-7-jre
  sun-java5-jre sun-java6-jre java5-runtime jre libreoffice-java-common
  libgnomeprintui2.2-0 libpod-plainer-perl hpijs-ppds hplip-doc wx2.8-doc
  wx2.8-examples editra dwww menu deborphan gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gromit
Recommended packages:
  rarian-compat
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  accountsservice acpi-support acpid aisleriot alsa-base alsa-utils anacron
  apparmor apport apport-gtk aptdaemon apturl at avahi-daemon avahi-utils
  bluez bluez-alsa bluez-cups bluez-gstreamer brasero brltty build-essential
  checkbox checkbox-qt colord compiz compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-main-default
  compizconfig-backend-gconf console-setup consolekit cron cryptsetup-bin cups
  dbus dbus-x11 dmsetup e2fsprogs eject empathy evolution-data-server
  friendly-recovery ftp g++ g++-4.6 gconf2 gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0 gksu
  gnome-bluetooth gnome-control-center gnome-disk-utility gnome-keyring
  gnome-media gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-session
  gnome-session-bin gnome-system-log gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data
  gnome-user-share grub-common grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-pc grub-pc-bin
  grub2-common gstreamer0.10-gconf gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse
  hostname hplip ibus ibus-pinyin ibus-table ifupdown indicator-datetime
  indicator-power indicator-printers indicator-session indicator-sound
  initramfs-tools initscripts ipheth-utils irqbalance jockey-common jockey-gtk
  kbd keyboard-configuration landscape-client-ui-install
  language-selector-common language-selector-gnome libc-dev-bin libc6-dev
  libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra-pulse
  libcompizconfig0 libcryptsetup4 libdevmapper-event1.02.1 libdevmapper1.02.1
  libfolks-eds25 libgdu0 libgksu2-0 libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0
  libgnome2-common libgweather-3-0 libgweather-common libimobiledevice4
  liblvm2app2.2 libmetacity-private0 libnih-dbus1 libnih1 libnm-gtk0
  libnss-mdns libparted0debian1 libreoffice-gnome libsane libstdc++6-4.6-dev
  libsyncdaemon-1.0-1 libubuntuoneui-3.0-1 libunique-3.0-0 light-themes
  lightdm linux-generic linux-image-3.2.0-29-generic linux-image-generic
  linux-sound-base logrotate media-player-info metacity metacity-common
  modemmanager module-init-tools mountall nautilus nautilus-sendto
  nautilus-share netbase network-manager network-manager-gnome
  network-manager-pptp network-manager-pptp-gnome ntfs-3g ntpdate oneconf
  parted plymouth plymouth-label plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text pm-utils policykit-1 policykit-1-gnome
  powermgmt-base ppp pppconfig pppoeconf pptp-linux printer-driver-gutenprint
  printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-postscript-hp procps pulseaudio
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-gconf pulseaudio-module-x11
  python-aptdaemon python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-aptdaemon.pkcompat
  python-ubuntu-sso-client python-ubuntuone-control-panel resolvconf rfkill
  rhythmbox rhythmbox-mozilla rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder
  rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins
  rhythmbox-ubuntuone rsyslog sane-utils seahorse sessioninstaller shotwell
  simple-scan software-center software-properties-gtk telepathy-salut telnet
  totem-mozilla ubuntu-artwork ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-sso-client
  ubuntu-sso-client-gtk ubuntu-standard ubuntu-system-service ubuntuone-client
  ubuntuone-client-gnome ubuntuone-control-panel ubuntuone-installer udev
  udisks ufw unity unity-2d unity-common unity-lens-applications
  unity-scope-musicstores update-manager update-notifier upower upstart
  ureadahead usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk usb-modeswitch
  usb-modeswitch-data util-linux whoopsie wpasupplicant xdiagnose xorg
  xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all
  xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-mouse
  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-ati
  xserver-xorg-video-cirrus xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-intel
  xserver-xorg-video-mach64 xserver-xorg-video-mga xserver-xorg-video-neomagic
  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
  xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-r128 xserver-xorg-video-radeon
  xserver-xorg-video-s3 xserver-xorg-video-savage
  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion xserver-xorg-video-sis
  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb xserver-xorg-video-tdfx xserver-xorg-video-trident
  xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware xul-ext-ubufox
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libept1.4.12 libframe6 libgeis1 libgrail5 libvte-common libvte9 synaptic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  brasero-cdrkit brasero-common compiz-core compiz-plugins-default
  empathy-common gir1.2-totem-1.0 libapt-pkg4.12 libbrasero-media3-1
  libdecoration0 libhpmud0 libperl5.14 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc
  libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gtk
  libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-writer libtotem0
  libunity-core-5.0-5 libwxbase2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-0 nautilus-sendto-empathy
  perl-base perl-modules printer-driver-hpijs python-uno python-wxgtk2.8
  python-wxversion totem totem-common totem-plugins unity-services uno-libs3
  ure
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  e2fsprogs util-linux (due to e2fsprogs) hostname upstart (due to hostname)
37 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 257 to remove and 434 not upgraded.
10 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 105 MB of archives.
After this operation, 394 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
 ?] no
Abort.
```

Now when I open Soft Ware Center I get this:

[image]

So I hit repair, then to get this message:

[image]

...and it keeps looping.

Any suggestions on how to get this working so I can install build-essentials and build my wifi drivers?

Comment: Do you have any PPA's or other repositories enabled? Also, please run `sudo apt-get update` and try again.

Comment: What wifi driver are you trying to build?

Comment: rt2870/mt7601u @artm

Comment: No other repositories. 'apt-get update' did not change anything.